# difference between javascript foreach loop, for..in and angular forEach loop.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

Iam new to angular framework. when i want to iterate json object in angular, i used javascript `foreach` and `for..in` loops.

Later i came to know that angular itself has a `angular.forEach` loop to iterate objects.

How can i compare performance of `angular.forEach` with javascript `for..in` and `foreach` loops??

Why we should use `angular.forEach` instead of javascript `foreach` and `for..in`??

Please give me some examples and reasons to use it, which shows the performance.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Angular forEach** - Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection, which can be either an object or an array.

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});

// Output:
// "name: misko"
// "gender: male"
```

**for..in** - iterates over the `enumerable properties` of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}

// Output:
// "obj.a = 1"
// "obj.b = 2"
// "obj.c = 3"
```

**forEach** - method executes a provided function once per array element.

```
// Notice that index 2 is skipped since there is no item at
// that position in the array.
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(function (element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
});
// logs:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[3] = 9
```

In terms of performance it depends on the data structure you're working with, if it's an `Array` I will suggest using `Angular.forEach or native forEach`, if it's an `Object` `for..in` will be the best, however it seems `Angular.forEach` handles object pretty well too. Depending on the amount of data you working with. If it's enormous I will suggest you use libraries like `Lodash or Underscore`, they handle data manipulation well.

Answer (score 11):

[`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) is basically a polyfill.

Therefore, if you are using angular, it doesn't matter if the browser is older because angular will provide a replacement if it's required.

In code it would look like this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(...) {
        // angulars own implementation
    }
}
```

There are some other differences, e.g.

- angular.forEach supports iteration over objects;
- angular.forEach takes an object/array as it's first argument.

Comment: True, the type of data structure also matter

Comment: It's wrong, `if (!Array.forEach) {` > `if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {`. `!Array.forEach` will always be `true` in this case. `forEach` is available in `prototype` property.

Comment: `angular.forEach` performance is better than the regular `for/foreach`?